# Chef - How to push to a single 'Test Server' in a pool?

Tags: chef-infra

I am setting up a new Chef environment and would like to know how to handle pushing a recipe to a single server in a pool for testing purposes. After testing passes, we will push the recipe to all servers.

The options I am thinking of:

- Use push jobs for everything
- Create a role specific to each server that executes the 'server-override' recipes
- Chef solo with an external job to manage copying of scripts

Has anyone had to do this before? Usually we like to test on one server before committing the change to the entire pool.

Comment: This is often referred to as a [Canary Deployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html) Strategy, but I've not seen it done with Chef yet. There is a [SO tag dedicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canary-deployment) to it but with only 3 questions. If you want some more reading, see if Programmers.SE or Server Fault have equivalent tags.

Comment: Why can't you use vagrant for provisioning VM and testing your recipe there?